# Sql - Using boolean logic in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a where clause that looks like this

```
WHERE   
    OnSideOffSideTotal  < Isnull(@OnsideOffsideUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND OnSideOffSideTotal  > Isnull(@OnsideOffsideLower, -9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal < Isnull(@GBPExposureUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal > Isnull(@GBPExposureLower, -9999999999999)
    AND UsedTolerancePercentage < Isnull(@UsedToleranceUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND UsedTolerancePercentage > Isnull(@UsedToleranceLower, -9999999999999)
```

it is basically allowing filtering within ceratin ranges to be specified for a report
If values are omitted then they default to a very larg positive or negative number

The problem I have is that certain users don't have a Tolerance defined, which means their Tolerance percentage will always be zero,

so if the report specifed a criteria like this

```
set @GBPExposureUpper = -7500
    set @OnsideOffsideUpper = -3
    set @UsedToleranceUpper = -100
```

then it would not include users who don't have a tolerance defined (as their tolerance will be zero - which is obviously larger than -100)

So I've created a bit field (@ShowNoSpecialTerms) which is controlled from a checkbox on the report which sets a flag to indicate that we want to addiionally include users who don't have a tolerance defined

When this is false we should use the filter conditions as normal

When this it is true, we should additionally include users who don't have a tolerance defined - these can be identified using the ToleranceLevel column

so the logic is kind of like

```
if (@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 0)

    OnSideOffSideTotal  < Isnull(@OnsideOffsideUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND OnSideOffSideTotal  > Isnull(@OnsideOffsideLower, -9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal < Isnull(@GBPExposureUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal > Isnull(@GBPExposureLower, -9999999999999)
    AND UsedTolerancePercentage < Isnull(@UsedToleranceUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND UsedTolerancePercentage > Isnull(@UsedToleranceLower, -9999999999999)

...

if  (@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 1)
--then additionally bring back result where ToleranceLevel=0
```

Have tried the following

```
WHERE   
    OnSideOffSideTotal  < Isnull(@OnsideOffsideUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND OnSideOffSideTotal  > Isnull(@OnsideOffsideLower, -9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal < Isnull(@GBPExposureUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal > Isnull(@GBPExposureLower, -9999999999999)
    AND (@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 0 OR
        UsedTolerancePercentage < Isnull(@UsedToleranceUpper, 9999999999999)
        AND UsedTolerancePercentage > Isnull(@UsedToleranceLower, -9999999999999))
```

This is half way to what I want - basically when    `@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 1` it ignores the rest of the tolerance check

However, what I want is for it to return he results or the tolerance check PLUS those users who have a ToleranceLevel of zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have solved it:

```
WHERE   
    OnSideOffSideTotal  < Isnull(@OnsideOffsideUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND OnSideOffSideTotal  > Isnull(@OnsideOffsideLower, -9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal < Isnull(@GBPExposureUpper, 9999999999999)
    AND GbpExposureClientTotal > Isnull(@GBPExposureLower, -9999999999999)
    AND ( 
            -- it falls in this tolerance range
            (UsedTolerancePercentage < Isnull(@UsedToleranceUpper, 9999999999999) AND UsedTolerancePercentage > Isnull(@UsedToleranceLower, -9999999999999)) 
            -- OR, if it falls outside of the range but the tolerance is zero AND we have asked these results to be additionally included
            OR(@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 1 AND ToleranceLevel = 0)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, [this is what you need](http://knvn.blog.com/2011/05/13/sql-conditional-wheret-sql/).

- Place **AND** between the condition `@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 0` and it’s
  true part.
- Apply the same procedure to `Else if` condition too i.e. place the **AND**
  between `@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 1` and its body part.
- Now place **OR** between these statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is still pretty unclear, but I think you want:

```
WHERE (normal conditions)
OR (@ShowNoSpecialTerms = 1 AND
    <Additional logic for those special users>).
```

The `OR` will only be used if the bit is flipped in that scenario.